# PrestaShop: How to find the origin of any peace of code that we see in browser's code source view?

Tags: content-management-system, prestashop

I am writting this post because I am sometimes confronted to this problem as a web developper. And I must admit I am a bit ashamed about it.

*Some peaces of codes are quite easy to find into a CMS content. But some are much harder.*

To illustrate my post I will give an example of a peace of code I really cannot find on a Prestashop website, see this photo:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MKmU.png)

So, I would like to find the origin of this script tag surrounded in red in the prestashop files...

First thing I tried was to search into the prestashop directory files for a string like => "**script type="text/javascript src="http://tatouagetemporaire .."**, I tested other strings but could not find a match.

My guess is that this peace of code is created from with a function (in php/JS or even smarty), and that is why I can't find any match in the whole code of the theme.

**So, my question:**

How can we find 100% of time the origin of any peace of code that we see in the browser's source code view ?

And if you have an answer for this specific case that would be very cool.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must turn off the CCC and cache from BackOffice to see the source codes